# Why do these horizontal lines appear when I don't use supports?

Tags: print-quality, print-preparation, elegoo-mars

I am trying to print several parts on my Elegoo Mars 3. When I support them, the parts come out fine. On the other hand, when not using supports (with 2 mm walls), a horizontal line appears in the same place and I don't understand why it appears. Could someone help me solve this?

[image: Photo of a resin printed model without supports and a horizontal line appears]

[image: Photo of a resin printed model with supports and no horizontal line is present]